# How to marshall out void* argument which can be one of two structs from interface?

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

I have an unmanaged interface I'm trying to marshal and use in C#.

And there is a function I'm not sure how to marshal correctly:

```
IDataInfo :
public IUnknown {
...
    STDMETHOD_(BOOL, GetDataPackInfo) (UINT packIndex, void* pPackExtendedInfo) = 0;
...
}
```

The `void*` can be one of two different structures:

```
struct DataExtendedInfoArchive {
    WORD Size;
    BOOL Archived;
    UINT SignalLength;
    BYTE Captured;
};

struct DataExtendedInfoStorage {
    WORD Size;
    FLOAT SignalFreq;
    UINT SignalLength;
    CHAR Code[4];
};
```

I implement those in C# like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TrackExtendedInfoAudio
{
    int Size;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    bool Archived;
    uint SignalLength;
    byte Captured;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TrackExtendedInfoVideo
{
    public int Size;
    public double SignalFreq;
    public uint SignalLength;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public StringBuilder Code;
}
```

The problem is I don't exactly understand what I'm going to get in `void* pPackExtendedInfo` and how to handle it and therefore don't know how to write a correct marshaling signature for this function.

Comment: There must be a way that you can know up front which flavor of struct you get back.  The caller (i.e. your C# code) has to allocate enough memory so the native code can scribble the structure without corrupting the heap.   The *packIndex* argument does not appear to be up to that task, you just don't know.  Only alternative is to call Marshal.AllocHGlobal() and allocate enough so that *both* structures can fit.  Then use Marshal.ReadInt32() so you can read the *Size* value back, then the appropriate Marshal.PtrToStructure().  Note that the Code field must be an array, UnmanagedType.ByValArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could marshal `void*` as `IntPtr`:

```
private static extern bool GetDataPackInfo(uint packIndex, [In,Out] IntPtr pPackExtendedInfo);
```

And copy structure using one of the [`Marshal.PtrToStructure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure(v=vs.110).aspx) (and [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr(v=vs.110).aspx)) methods:

```
IntPtr p = IntPtr.Zero;
GetDataPackInfo(..., p);
TrackExtendedInfoAudio audioInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure<TrackExtendedInfoAudio>(p);
```

or

```
TrackExtendedInfoVideo videoInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure<TrackExtendedInfoVideo>(p);
```

---

*PS. And I'm not sure the `StringBuilder` is an appropriate marshaling for the `CHAR Code[4];`.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer and PS! I reviewed my structures and noticed a few types were a bit off.

Answer (score 2):

The managed function signature (minus attributes and decorations) should be:

```
// make sure that the return is marshalled as UnmanagedTypes.Boolean.
bool GetDataPackInfo(uint packIndex, IntPtr pPackExtendedInfo);
```

To unpack the struct, first you need to determine which one you're working with. Fortunately the first member of each is a size parameter, which will give a clue as to the size of the struct.  To read that size, then unpack the structure:

```
IntPtr ptr; // this is the pointer passed to your callback.

int cbSize = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr, 0);
if (cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(TrackExtendedInfoAudio))
{
    TrackExtendedInfoAudio s = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(TrackExtendedInfoAudio)) 
             as TrackExtendedInfoAudio;
    // Processing...
}
else if (cbSize == Marshal.SizeOf(TrackExtendedInfoVideo))
{
    TrackExtendedInfoVideo s = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(TrackExtendedInfoVideo)) 
             as TrackExtendedInfoVideo;
    // Processing...
}
else
{
    // unknown struct
}
```